# Diophantine equation and regular polygons

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations, polygons

Consider Diophantine equation:

$$(m-4)n=2m.$$

It can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{m}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

If we search for positive solutions only, we have at least $4$ pairs:

$$(m,n)\in\{(5,10);(6,6);(8,4);(12;3)\}$$

They can be illustrated in the following way using regular polygons:

[image]

> How are the equation and the polygon combinations related? Do we have any other positive solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's $$mn-2m-4n=0$$ or
$$(m-4)(n-2)=8$$ and we get a finite number of cases:

1. $m-4=1$ and $n-2=8$, which gives $(m,n)=(5,10)$;
2. $m-4=2$ and $n-2=4$, which gives $(m,n)=(6,6)$;
3. $m-4=4$ and $n-2=2$, which gives $(m,n)=(8,4)$ and
4. $m-4=8$ and $n-2=1$, which gives $(m,n)=(12,3)$.

Easy to see that these all natural solutions.

Answer (score 3):

In a regular polygon with $m$ sides, each internal angle measures
$$
180°\cdot{m-2\over m}.
$$
If you join two such equal polygons along a common side, they form an outside angle of
$$
360°- 2\cdot180°\cdot{m-2\over m}=360°\cdot{2\over m}.
$$
You can go on joining other polygons, always on the same side: the chain will close if the angle computed above is the internal angle of a regular polygon with $n$ sides, for some value of $n$. That happens if:
$$
360°\cdot{2\over m}=180°\cdot{n-2\over n},
$$
which is equivalent to your equation. The solutions of this equation then represent the only possible "regular polygon closed chains" one can obtain. See the other answers for a proof that there are only four possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but I accepted Michael's answer since he gave it first and I can't accept both

Answer (score 1):

Its $n=\frac{2m}{m-4}$ and thus $m-4 \mid 2m$. It follows that $m-4 \mid 2m-2(m-4)=8$. So $m-4=1, 2, 4, 8$ and $m=5, 6, 8, 12$.